# Macport is not installing

Tags: macos, macports

I want to install boost using `Macport`. I have successfully installed `Xcode`, its command line tools and `Macports`. Still I am getting the following error:

```
Error: Unable to execute port: Could not open file: /Users/jay.thakkar/Downloads/MacPorts-2.2.0-archive/dports/devel/boost/Portfile
```

Comment: I think that macports isn't installed correctly. Portfiles are normally located at /opt/local/var/macports/... I would try to install macports again.

Comment: Does the command "port" work?